# TIP - how to change position hover effect

Tags: html, css

I have try add to my website script with help tip. I want change position hover effect because now is wrong. Anyone help me how can I to do?

Here I add screen with Currently effect:
[image]

here I paste +/- expected result:
[image]

```css
    .help-tip{
        position: absolute;
        top: 55px;
        right: 11px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #BCDBEA;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 26px;
        cursor: default;
    }
    
    .help-tip:before{
        content:'?';
        font-weight: bold;
        color:#fff;
    }
    
    .help-tip:hover p{
        display:block;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
        animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    
    }
    
    .help-tip p{    /* The tooltip */
        display: none;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #1E2021;
        padding: 60px;
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        right: -4px;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }
    
    .help-tip p:before{ /* The pointer of the tooltip */
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        width:0;
        height: 0;
        border:6px solid transparent;
        border-bottom-color:#1E2021;
        right:10px;
        top:-12px;
    }
    
    .help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        top:-40px;
        left:0;
    }
    
    /* CSS animation */
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
        0% { 
            opacity:0; 
            transform: scale(0.6);
        }
    
        100% {
            opacity:100%;
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        0% { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:100%; }
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="help-tip">
    <p>MSRP - Sugerowana cena sprzedaży przez producenta</p>
</div>
```

Anyone provide any solution?

I can put this topic because system return error:
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change css for .help-tip p and .help-tip p:before

```css
    .help-tip{
        position: absolute;
        top: 55px;
        right: 11px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #BCDBEA;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 26px;
        cursor: default;
    }
    
    .help-tip:before{
        content:'?';
        font-weight: bold;
        color:#fff;
    }
    
    .help-tip:hover p{
        display:block;
        transform-origin: 100% 0%;
    
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
        animation: fadeIn 0.3s ease-in-out;
    
    }
    
    .help-tip p {
display: none;
text-align: left;
background-color: #1E2021;
padding: 10px;
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
border-radius: 3px;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
right: -4px;
top: -60px;
color: #FFF;
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.4;
}

.help-tip p:before {
position: absolute;
content: '';
width: 0;
height: 0;
transform: rotate(178deg);
border: 6px solid transparent;
border-bottom-color: #1E2021;
right: 10px;
bottom: -12px;
}
    
    .help-tip p:after{ /* Prevents the tooltip from being hidden */
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        content:'';
        position: absolute;
        top:-40px;
        left:0;
    }
    
    /* CSS animation */
    
    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
        0% { 
            opacity:0; 
            transform: scale(0.6);
        }
    
        100% {
            opacity:100%;
            transform: scale(1);
        }
    }
    
    @keyframes fadeIn {
        0% { opacity:0; }
        100% { opacity:100%; }
    }
    </style>
```

```html
<div class="help-tip">
    <p>MSRP - Sugerowana cena sprzedaży przez producenta</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I see we have small issue in mobile view: https://prnt.sc/s3teu7  We use:  media (max-width: 767px){   }  Could you help us to set this also for mobile view

Comment: add max-width to .help-tip it will fix you problem

Comment: I add to .help-tip{ max-width but no work. Can you please again check and help us to solve this issue with wrong display on mobile view?

Comment: add this code to your mobile media query
.help-tip p {
      text-align: center;
      width: 180px;
      top: -79px;
    }

Comment: @Sylvester Welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can change this by changing the `absolute positioning` of the `tooltip`.

You need to move the `tooltip` above the question mark, and flip the pointer of the tooltip. This code should fix it:

```
.help-tip p {
  bottom: 30px;
}


.help-tip p:before {
  right: 10px;
  bottom: -12px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

It will move the tooltip above the question. I've added the code to alter the `:before` so that the pointer is below, not above, and then rotated it.